# Can't get data from firestore collection

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have structured my data like this.
[image]

I want get all the orders collection. My data flow is collection > document > collection > document

I have tried to get data with this code

```
       db.collection('users')
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
            const orders = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
            console.log(orders);
       });
```

It didn't work.
How can I get all the orders inside an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is querying the collection "users", but your screenshot is showing a subcollection "users/{email}/orders".  If you want to query the subcollection, you will have to build a CollectionReference to the subcollection you want to query:

```
db
    .collection("users")
    .doc("email-address")
    .collection("orders")
    .get()
```

If you want all of the orders for all of the users, then you need a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).

```
db.collectionGroup("orders").get()
```